# how can I reset or refresh DataGridView Cell back color?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am facing problem regarding DataGridView cell back color.

Firstly I m changing datagridview2's specific cell's back color.

```
int cnt = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            string starting = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            string startings = Convert.ToDateTime(starting.ToString()).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
            string ending = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            string endings = Convert.ToDateTime(ending.ToString()).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");

            TimeSpan ts = Convert.ToDateTime(ending.ToString()) - Convert.ToDateTime(starting.ToString());
            double diff = ts.TotalDays + 1;
            int dif = Convert.ToInt32(diff);
            for (int d = 0; d < dif; d++)
            {
                string str = Convert.ToDateTime(starting.ToString()).AddDays(d).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[str].Style.BackColor = Color.Olive;
            }
        }
```

I need to reset the back color according to new value entered in datagridview1. here is my code.

```
Private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 7 || e.ColumnIndex == 8 || e.ColumnIndex == 9 || e.ColumnIndex == 10)
        {
            int prd_per_d = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value);
            int qty=Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value);
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value = qty / prd_per_d + 5;

            DateTime sdt = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value);
            int req_day = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value);
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value = sdt.AddDays(req_day);

            int cnt = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                string starting = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                string startings = Convert.ToDateTime(starting.ToString()).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
                string ending = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                string endings = Convert.ToDateTime(ending.ToString()).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");

                TimeSpan ts = Convert.ToDateTime(ending.ToString()) - Convert.ToDateTime(starting.ToString());
                double diff = ts.TotalDays + 1;
                int dif = Convert.ToInt32(diff);

                for (int d = 0; d < dif; d++)
                {
                    string str = Convert.ToDateTime(starting.ToString()).AddDays(d).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");

                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[str].Style.BackColor = Color.Olive;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

But There is no viewable changes happen when I entered value in datagridview1. It works only for new cell but does not change for existing colored cell to default.
any idea why?

Comment: Hm, so you are missing ui updates from the `CellEndEdit` event, right? It may well be that it restricts itself to refreshing the edited cell. Maybe you should add an DGV.Refresh call at the end?

Comment: Hm, are you sure about those Cell/Column names? I doubt that they can have spaces in them..! Should throw an exception, though, imo

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Problem about one week ago. I solved it with just 2 rows of programmcode. Hope this will help you to! :

```
        this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
        this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
```